# How do I configure the Linux kernel within Buildroot?

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel, buildroot

I'm trying to build a rootfs for an x86 target, which is all simple enough.  However I can't figure out how I configure the kernel that buildroot produces.  The first run through came up with menuconfig, but it's cached the .config since then and I can't see where to change it.

~650MB of kernel modules don't do good things to an embedded target :P

Is there an easy way to configure the kernel within buildroot?  Something like the `uclibc-menuconfig` target would be perfect.

Comment: This might be better answered at http://ServerFault.com/ or http://SuperUser.com/ maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is:

```
make linux26-menuconfig
```

Comment: In 2019 this answer is no longer correct, it should be: make linux-menuconfig

Answer (score 48):

I always do the following:

1. configure Linux kernel: `make linux-menuconfig`
2. After leaving menuconfig your configuration will be stored in file: `output/build/linux-XYZ/.config` where *XYZ* is your kernel version.
3. After that you can copy file  `output/build/linux-*XYZ*/.config` to `board/your_kernel_config/.config`
4. later in Buildroot menuconfig you can under kernel settings configure to use custom kernel config file and enter path: `board/your_kernel_config/.config`

Comment: `make linux-xconfig` works as well. It has the added benefit that if you search for something, you can select it in the search window, and it updates the main window to the location of that item.

Comment: this should be the first answer

Answer (score 3):

Do not forget to set also defconfig to i386 in menuconfig:

```
  Kernel  —>
  [*] Linux Kernel
  (i386) Defconfig name
```

Answer (score 3):

**`BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES`**

Adds extra configs to your existing one.

E.g., if you are using `buildroot` as a submodule, the directory tree looks like:

```
.git/
buildroot/
.gitmodules
kernel-config-frag
```

E.g. to turn on `CONFIG_DEBUG_FS`, do:

```
echo 'CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y' > kernel-config-frag
```

and then configure buildroot with:

```
cd buildroot
make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
echo 'BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES=../kernel-config-frag' >> buildroot/.config
make
```

This way you can git track just a diff between `qemu_x86_64_defconfig` and your extra configs.

I believe this uses `scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh` form the kernel as mentioned at: [How do you non-interactively turn on features in a Linux kernel .config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505164/how-do-you-non-interactively-turn-on-features-in-a-linux-kernel-config-file/39440863#39440863)

After you change the config fragment, just remember to do:

```
rm -rf buildroot/output/build/linux-*.*.*/
```

before the next build.

Minimal runnable example at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/bb8f4eb79565c9771356c80e0964c8fefc163e11/kernel-config-frag

**`BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE`**

Selects the full `.config` to be used.

For some reason I have to nuke the kernel's `.config` for this to take effect? [Why when I change BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE and run make linux-reconfigure the kernel .config does not change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260466/why-when-i-change-br2-linux-kernel-custom-config-file-and-run-make-linux-reconfi)

Answer (score 0):

The steps are as follows:

1. `cd buildroot/`
2. `make menuconfig`
3. Kernel -> Linux Kernel  -> Kernel version