# why buildroot fails to make the .config?

Tags: makefile, buildroot

I'm somehow new to buildroot makefile and I created my own configuration file for a new operating system. After typing

**`make menuconfig`**

I saw that the buildroot has made the .config file. but when I type

**`make`**

it gives the following error:

```
linux/linux.mk:69: *** No kernel device tree source specified, check your BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_INTREE_DTS / BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_DTS settings.  Stop.
```

what does it mean ? what did I forget to include in buildroot configuration menu ?

I searched the internet and didn't find anything useful ... I've looked at the build root documentation and didn't find anything neither ....

Comment: In Buildroot's kernel config menu, what do you have selected for Kernel version (static version number, Custom Git tree, Custom tarball, etc...)?  Do you have Device tree support selected?  If so, did you specify the Device tree source?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the buildroot .config, you need a linux config. You can create one by:

```
make linux-menuconfig
```

See:

[How do I configure the Linux kernel within Buildroot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414968/how-do-i-configure-the-linux-kernel-within-buildroot)

http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#kernel-custom

Answer (score 0):

Which board do you plan to run the produced image on? Which platform are you building for? Check the output of the following command:

```
grep ^BR2_ARCH .config
```

If it is `i386` or `x86_64`, you likely do not need Device Tree support, so just disable it using `make menuconfig` (search for `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_INTREE_DTS` or `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_DTS` by pressing `/`).

Also check out http://elinux.org/Device_Tree for a detailed description of Device Tree.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have a device tree source file set.  There's several different reasons for this.  The first thing to check is:

```
make menuconfig
```

Select the Kernel options.  Near the bottom is the option for "**Device tree source**".  If that's set to "**Use a custom device tree file**" and you don't have a good path set in the next option, "**Device Tree Source file paths**", then you will get this error.  Alternatively, if it's set to "**Use a device tree present in the kernel**" and the "**Device Tree Source file names**" option is blank or the name(s) have .dts at the end, you may get this error.