# Why when I change BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE and run make linux-reconfigure the kernel .config does not change?

Tags: buildroot

Buildroot 7d43534625ac06ae01987113e912ffaf1aec2302 post 2018.02, Ubuntu 17.10 host.

I run:

```
make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
printf 'BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=\"kdb\"\n' >>.config
make olddefconfig
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)"
```

where kdb is a Linux kernel configuration that has `CONFIG_KGDB=y`.

Then as expected:

```
grep '^CONFIG_KGDB=y' ./output/build/linux-4.15/.config
```

has a match.

But then I want to try out a new kernel config, so I try:

```
sed -i 's/BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=kdb/BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=nokdb/'
```

where `nokdb` is a kernel config that has `CONFIG_KGDB=n` and then:

```
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)" linux-reconfigure
```

However to my surprise, the kernel `.config` did not change, `CONFIG_KGDB=y` is still there.

Only if I do:

```
rm -f ./output/build/linux-4.15/.config
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)" linux-reconfigure
```

Is there a better way to force the kernel `.config` to be regenerated, e.g. some other `linux-*` target?

I don't like this `rm` solution because it forces me to deal with "internal" paths inside `output`.

I'd  expect `linux-reconfigure` to do that regeneration for me.

Analogous behavior if you turn `BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_INITRAMFS` on and off, which affects the `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE` option of the Linux kernel.

http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-March/215817.html

Answer (score 1):

The config files are checked for timestamps, so after you do:

```
touch kdb
touch nokdb
printf 'BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=\"kdb\"\n' >>.config
make olddefconfig
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)"
```

`kdb` and `nokdb` have the same modified date, and the kernel does not get reconfigured on the next:

```
sed -i 's/BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=kdb/BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=nokdb/'
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)" linux-reconfigure
```

But if you touch the new config file, it works, even without using the `linux-reconfigure` target explicitly:

```
touch nokdb
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)"
```

Alternatively, if you just edit the used file instead of pointing to a new one, the configuration also gets updated as expected.